# Mapping software for salesmen on the road

Tags: maps

We've used Autoroute in the past because you can upload a dataset of customer delivery addresses and then, when a salesman is visiting customer X, you can enter the postcode and a radius and pull up nearby addresses that might be worth a visit.

As AutoRoute is approaching end of life. I'm looking for an alternative.

It should:

- Allow for multiple datasets (red pushpins for salesman A, yellow for salesman B).
- Be easy enough to update (ultimately from a SQL Server source).
- Be available on Blackberries, via an app or web based.

We're not *so* concerned about routing as the salesmen have satnavs they know and love.

Comment: What operating system(s)?

Comment: Just needs to be available via BlackBerry - so web based really